# Taylor expansion and its identity problem

Tags: calculus, integration, taylor-expansion

> Let $u = u(x,y)$ be a smooth scalar field on $\mathbb R^2$ with a global minimum at the origin,
>
> $u(0,0)$ =: $u_0<u(x,y)$. By Taylor expanding $u$ to second order around the origin, show that
>
> one has the approximate identity
>
> $\int_{R^2}$  exp$[-\lambda u(x,y)]d^2x$ $\approx \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\frac{e^{-\lambda u_0}}{\sqrt {k_1 k_2}}$
>
> The parameters $k_1$ and $k_2$ are the principal curvatures of $u$ at the origin, and $\lambda$ is an arbitrary
>
> positive real number. Which parameter governs the quality of the approximation.

By convention, if $u(x,y)$ is just continuous, then we say $u(x,y) \in C^{(0)}(\Omega)$.

Also, $u(x,y) \in C^{(\infty)}$ if the function is differentiable any number of times. For instance, $e^{x} \in C^{(\infty)}$. I am confused the function itself where I have to Taylor expand to the second order. Any help or guide to this problem will be appreciated.

Comment: The Taylor expansion to second order is $$u(x,y) |_{(0,0)} = u(0,0) + xu_{x}(0,0) + yu_{y}(0,0) + \frac{1}{2!} [x^{2}u_{xx}(0,0) + xu_{xy}(0,0) + y^{2}u_{yy}(0,0)]$$ Shouldn't the integrand be $\exp(-\lambda u(x,y))$ not $\exp(-\lambda u(x))$? Otherwise you won't be integrating over $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

Comment: apologies I have edited to u(x,y). Thanks for the guide I have one question. From the Taylor expansion how should I approach from there to derive the identity given in the question? seems like its gaussian integral, but since the question deals with the taylor expansion am really confused..

Comment: **Hint:** What happens to $e^{-t}$ when $t$ is large? And how fast does the exponential function decay? Now, consider that $u(0,0)$ is the minimum of your function which implies that the rest of the terms are larger than $u(0,0)$ in magnitude.